# jQuery is() selector not rendering results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using is() selector which must provide me some results, but it ain't happening.

***HTML:***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div p").is(":nth-child(2)").css("border","2px solid red");

    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <div>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

***EXPECTATION:***

I was expecting two lines to be in red (7th and 12th) paragraph, but instead I am getting an error.

***ERROR:***

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).is(...).css is not a function

***NOTE:***

> I want to do this with .is() selector only.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why are you not using an inline snippet?? this way it's impossible to see/understand/edit the code!

Comment: how to use inline snippet ? pls tell ...

Comment: Google: stackoverflow inline snippet. show some effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it as follows. Because `.is()` will give you boolean value which can not have `.css()` function.

```
$("div p:nth-child(2)").css("border","2px solid red");
```

**UPDATE**

Its possible this way

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8mns5sex/1/)

```
$("div p").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":nth-child(2)"))
    {
        $(this).css("border","2px solid red");
    }
});
```